# API to create entries in wiktionary

Tags: python, mediawiki, wiktionary

I am looking for an API with documentation for writing entries in Wiktionary.
I wish to create entries for new words from a local database.
Preferably in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python package called [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) that should fit the bill.

It does support editing and page creation via the [page.save(text)](https://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/page-ops.html#editing-or-creating-a-page) method but of course you will need to have [signed in](https://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/connecting.html#authenticating) with appropriate credentials.

It is pip installable and is actively maintained.